# Backbone.js: Binding event to template button

Tags: javascript, templates, backbone.js, underscore.js, backbone-events

I'm building an application with Backbone.js where a list of items and a placeholder "new" item are displayed. The container is a view that holds all the sub-views and renders them.

I have searched for some time now but can't get it to work.
The problem is that the "Add" button in the template is not firing the event. I guess it's because of the rendering taking place at a later point in time and so the event is not assigned. Reading other posts this should be taken care of by Backbone.js but it doesn't seem that way. Adding a jQuery event handler after `render()` does the job but I think that cannot be the solution.

Here's the relevant code of the view:

```
template: _.template($("#template-time-new").html()),
events: {
  'click #btn-new-time': 'onButtonNewClick'
},
render: function() {
  this.$el.html(this.template());

  return this;
},

onButtonNewClick: function() {
  return false; // in this case: prevent page reload
}
```

My template (jade):

```
script(type="text/template", id="template-time-new").
<h3>
  <label for="new-time-name" class="muted">Name:</label>
  <input id="new-time-name" type="text">
</h3>
<div class="time-inner">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <label for="new-time-start" class="muted">From:</label>
    <input id="new-time-start" type="datetime-local">

    <label for="new-time-end" class="muted">to</label> 
    <input id="new-time-end" type="datetime-local">

    <button class="btn" id="btn-new-time">
      Add
    </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Here's the code from the parent view:

```
initialize: function() {
  this.newView = new TimeSpanNewView; // <---- the view that is not really working

  this.render();

  // bind event handlers
  this.collection.on('all', this.render, this);
  // fetch data
  this.collection.fetch();
},

render: function() {
  var self = this;

  self.$el.empty();

  if ( self.collection.length > 0 ) {
    self.collection.each(function(timespan) {
      var subView = new TimeSpanView({ // sub views for the items, everything fine here
        model: timespan
      });

      subView.render()
      self.$el.append(subView.el);
    });
  } else {
    self.$el.text("Nothing found.");
  }

  self.$el.append(self.newView.render().el);

  return self;
}
```

Comment: Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/MNJd5/ What are you doing differently? And that `<button>` really should be a `<button type="button">`.

Comment: Nothing, that's why I posed this question. Tried it out with adding this.delegateEvents(); [like posted as an answer that disappeared] and it works perfectly fine now.

Comment: What version of Backbone are you using?

Comment: I would request more code. I have similar problem so I want to see how you use you view in parent view.

Comment: v1.0.0, current version from website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removed previous comment.
Well, you have to render it everytime, in `render()` of the parent view. But instead of doing `self.$el.html("");` try `self.$el.children().detach()`.
And add child view as

```
self.$el.append(self.newView.render().el);
```

Explanation: $el already contains your child view and you don't want to completely remove the child view. So you need to call detach() on this - it removes DOM object for child view from page but doesn't remove it entirely.

Comment: no I simply render this view once. also insert it only once because it is cleaned out every time (only way I thought it was possible).

Comment: updated my answer, try it. As I see from your code it probably exactly your problem. It it works I update answer with explanation.

Comment: No sorry, already did that. Thanks for you tip, I'll now use this way to render in all of my projects. But sadly didn't fix the problem that the event handler does not fire.

Comment: I have only used your help, but yet the event problem is not solved.

Comment: Urgh, I messed up with these edits. Not $el.empty(), but $el.children().detach().

Comment: Wow great! That works absolutely fine! Thank you very much indeed!

Comment: Explanation seems logical, though of the same after reading the jQuery docs. Thanks again!